# IPython kernels: specifying default directory in kernel.json

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

When defining my own custom `ipython`/`jupyter` kernels, is there a way to set a kernel specific default directory directly in the `kernel.json` file?

```
{
 "argv": [ "python2", "-m", "IPython.kernel",
          "-f", "{connection_file}"],
 "display_name": "tmp_kernel",
 "language": "python"
}
```

My goal is to create a `kernel` that per default creates its notebooks in my `/tmp` directory.
At the moment I am starting `ipython` in multiple terminals, which is rather inconvenient.

Comment: That's not possible, because kernels don't create notebooks. Do you want a way to test out bits of code without saving them anywhere permanent? We are planning a web console which will integrate with the notebook to do exactly this.

Comment: @ThomasK, I think the webconsole is a nice idea. On a second thought my problem is not necessarily related to kernels at all. I guess it would already help to have some kind of a list of my favorite notebook folders with an option to easily change between them.